# Sitecore 9.2 JSS with Solr 7.5 , JSS route items and its subitems are not indexing

Tags: solr, jss, indexing

Currently we are developing Sitecore JSS app with React frontend. in this we are using Headless SSR mode to create the content in sitecore and rendering.

our application is working fine with React, but I am facing issue when I am trying to Index Sitecore content. My index is showing me successfully completed but its indexing template of my JSS app, its not indexing my JSS "Route" content Items which I have created under my content tree.

I trying to resolved but still no luck, also I checked all the configuration , path of content tree its correct there no issue, but my JSS content node is not indexing.

**Is any extra setting or configuration is required for Sitecore JSS content Tree solr indexing.**

Could you please help on this., Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the index config file you are rebuilding?